# Is there a Java Data API independent of persistence technology

Tags: java, mapping, persistence

I'm looking for an API that accesses data independently of the underlying persistence technology. CRUD and some search ability would be enough.

I need this for a situation where an UI application shall adopt easily to a changing data layer and we cannot have any control over that changes. Those changes could be for example

- some new or changed data fields
- change of structure from table to tree
- change from SOAP to REST
- change from SQL to REST

There are several approaches to solve this for a certain group of persistence technologies. For example

- JPA makes the application developer independent from the SQL vendor
- JSR 283 delivers independence from the underlying CMS system
- MS ODBC drivers give transparent access not only to SQL but also to CSV and Excel
- Java-XML-Mappers (JAXB, ...), well, they do NOT make us independent at all

But no solution I found so far can handle several technologies together.

Maybe this would be the holy grail of persistence, but maybe there is a solution and I just didn't find it.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is **JDO** Java Data Object.

Other than JPA there are implementations for more than only RDBMS systems. Also the list of functionalities can be seen as superset of JPA.

JDO is less popular than JPA, although very old, as it's first JRS was JSR-12. It's still alive; last update on specification 3.1 was done in 2015.

Find some information about JDO here: http://db.apache.org/jdo/index.html

An comprehencive implementation is DataNucleus as it supports many persistence technologies: http://www.datanucleus.org/index.html
 - APIs Supported : JDO 3.2, JPA 2.2+, REST
 - Mapping Supported : JDO, JPA
 - Datastores Supported : RDBMS, Excel, OOXML, ODF, XML, HBase, MongoDB, Cassandra, Neo4j, JSON, Amazon S3, GoogleStorage, LDAP

Answer (score 1):

Java Persistence API (JPA) is pretty common for this. There are many providers already available. You can also create your own JPA Provider for custom backend if needed.

The problem of common and abstract API layer is that its limited by a "common denominator" across all other possible providers. Sometimes you have to break this abstraction to manipulate data in a more efficient, platform-specific way. Pay attention to this in your planning and hope it works out well!

Comment: I'll give it a try. Together with EclipseLink+MOXy and meet-in-the-midddle mapping